# instant messaging program - works with 127.0.0.1, but not with other computers

Tags: c++, sockets, winapi, tcp

I have followed a tutorial on [http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/beginningtcp_cpp.aspxt](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/beginningtcp_cpp.aspx)

which teaches how to use winsockets with c++, i finally managed to get my program to work, by testing wiht 127.0.0.1, i can open two process instances of my program and then make one listen on port (700) and then connect to it with the other program on port 700 with ip 127.0.0.1, i can then send messages between the two programs with no problems.

I sent the program to my friend, got his ip and told him to start listening on port 700, then i tried to connect to his ip address and port 700, the program froze for about 20 seconds (because i have it on the same thread as my window) and the connect() function returns SOCKET_ERROR here:

```
if (connect(g_sock, (SOCKADDR*)&target, sizeof(target)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    return 4;
}
```

I have tried other ports and i have allowed it on windows firewall.. disabled window firewall too, disabled avast.

my code is almost the same as the one in the tutorial, and i have also downloaded the one in the tutorial and i get the same erro as mine.

I am using windows 7 ultimate 32 bit

Comment: Is this all on an internal network? Because if not you need to use the public IP address your friend accesses the internet through and configure that router to forward port 700 to his private IP address.

Comment: Im using the internet IP, which im getting from http://www.whatismyip.com/,

Comment: It is also always good idea to run Wireshark and catch traffic. This could give you idea what is wrong.

Comment: Most likely your friend is behind a firewall.  He can listen on that port all day long but unless his router is forwarding to his machine it isn't going to get to him.

Comment: We both have routers, so how would oyu forward it to the machine?
how come i can just go on the internet, download an iming program such as msn, install it and straight away msn has got past the router, firewall and avast without any hastle?

Comment: @kaijethegreat - In that instance you are the client connecting to the IM server, which allows you through its firewall.  Your friend's firewall/router has that port shut down even though his machine has it open.

Comment: @kaijethegreat - There is even more to what MSN does, it can reconfigure your router using UPnP.  Most important, it reconfigures your Windows firewall.  Possibly both you and your friend have Windows firewall enabled?  MSN also modifies the Windows firewall settings.

Comment: we both have windows firewall off, and anyway, when we first ran the program, windows firewall prompted us to either allow or not allow the connection, we allowed it. 

so in msn, if im the client, and my friends the client, and i send a message to the msn server, how does the msn server then send that message to my freidn and get past his router?

Comment: @kaijethegreat - because your friend logged in to the server also.  In simplest terms the server keeps track of each of your IPs and acts like the man in middle of a bucket brigade passing info back and forth.  (Just have him forward the router port to his machine - usually configurable through a web interface.)

Comment: i understand abit more now :) so would it be possible for me to forward my router, then me to act as a server (listening on port 700) and then my friend (with his unconfigured router) to connect to me?

Comment: Ok i got it working now :) forwarded ports 700-800 and then my freidn could connect to me. shame i can't vote a comment as the best answer!

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working.  It's not always about the points.  I still haven't figured out how to spend them anyway. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is either one of you behind a NAT firewall/router?  The IP address you present to the outside world might not be the one that your own computer uses, which would make it impossible for the program to communicate with you unless you had some sort of tunnel set up through the NAT.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying this across the Internet? There could be a firewall somewhere between both computers.

Ideally, you should **test your program on a Local Area Network first**. That's a more appropriate environment for this kind of test.